# How to pass a class function (ClassName::function) reference in c++ MACRO

Tags: c++, unit-testing, macros

I want to create an Macro that will help in unit testing for c++. where i do not want to create a new object for only testing purposes. **Is it possible to pass a class function reference like (ClassName::function) ?**

```
#define TEST(func_ptr,X,Expercted) \
(__extension__ ( \
{ \
  __typeof__(X) __x = (X); \
  __typeof__(Expercted) __y = (Expercted); \
  result= funct_ptr(__x);\
  //------- do some testing stuffs-----\
 } \
))
```

I have a Class A and its method square()

```
int main(){
  TEST(&A::square,2,4);
  return 0;
 }
```

I want to test whether the square function returns the true value.

**The Above codes gives error. How to solve the problem. Solution in other ways is appreciable**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a **non static member function pointer**, which requires a class instance to call. If you **change that to a static member or a free function**, it should work OK.

```
class A{
    ...
    static bool square(...);
};

TEST(A::square,...);
```

or

```
bool square(...);

TEST(square,...);
```

Also your macro has a typo - func_ptr vs funct_ptr

Comment: It gives an error
'funct_ptr' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @sayemsiam look at your Macro definition again, there is a typo thats causing the issue..

Comment: It was a typo, Thanks @Karthik T

Answer (score 2):

According to standard you cannot call non-static member function without creating an object. That's why you should create an **object** of `A` (for ex. `A a`) and call like this

```
A a;
TEST( std::bind( &A::square, &a ), 2, 4 );
```

If you'll ask if it's a nice idea to use macroses for purposes like that, I'll tell you - NO. Write a function instead. Like this

```
template< class F, class Ex >
bool test( F f, Ex expected ) {
    Ex res = f();
    return res == expected;
}
...
assert( test( std::bind( &A::square, &a, 2 ), 4 ) );
```

Comment: It gives an error 'bind' : is not a member of 'std'

Comment: What compiler do you use? And what is it's version?

Comment: did you `#include <functional>` ? If yes, then try `#include <tr1/functional> ` and change `std::bind` to `std::tr1::bind`